# Is it possible to automate a web search between two databases?

Tags: database, search, automation, web

I am wondering if anyone out there can shed some light to my current predicament:

For arguments sake, lets say there exists database A and B.

A stores data about car registration plates. When you enter a registration number into this database it returns the make and model of a car.

B stores data about the make and model of cars, such as number of seats, engine size, color, etc.

Both of these search engines exist on the web. Is it possible to automate a search between these 2 engines, so that the information returned when searching database A is used as a search term for database B?

I am not looking for the whole answer, just some pointers as to whether this problem can be solved by automating it, and what languages would be helpful to complete such a task.

Thank you in advance, MD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

OK, you wanted a little more than that. You're probably after something like a workflow engine. There are many such engines, and which is best will depend on your particular needs. For business-y type uses, you're probably best off with one based on [BPEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Execution_Language) (alas, not my area of expertise). For the case where you're looking to just automate the gluing together of DB queries on the web, you might consider a system from the scientific community instead. I work on one of the workflow engines in this space ([Taverna](http://www.taverna.org.uk/)) and I know *for sure* it can do this sort of thing, but there are other candidates too.

For the record, the difference between business and scientific workflow systems is mostly in how they handle errors: business workflows devote much attention to recovering from errors, whereas scientific workflows tend to carefully throw away the errors (well, mark them as cases to be ignored). Which is right for your situation?

Comment: The use case sounds a lot like bioinformatics: a significant fraction of that discipline is done by correlating queries to databases exposed on the Web. Given that, use that sort of tech…

Comment: Thank you Donal, this has been of some help in pointing me in the correct direction for my application.